# How to use spring form with bootstrap and display success Message in spring mvc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use spring with bootstrap its getting an like
 **Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute**
How to display registration success message when records are inserted into the data base?

**This is mapping error where I should have correct**
after introducing spring tags itself am getting using normal html and form working correctly.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>   



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h3 class="page-header"><b>Student Enrollment</b></h3>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                     Basic Information for admin
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                             <div class="form-body">                             


                 <div align="center">
        <form:form action="register" method="post">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Spring MVC Form Demo - Registration</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy):</td>
                    <td><form:input path="birthDate" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>




                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
```

**Controller class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public class RegisterController {


        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user) {         



            return "RegistrationSuccess";
        }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Spring-Registration</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>StudentEnrollmentFromAdmin.jsp</welcome-file>    
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- Single Servlet -->
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security configuration file -->
     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml,
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: When do you get this exception?

Comment: on startup of server

Comment: You need to add the `modelAttribute` as an attribute of the model before loading the page where you are trying to use it.

Comment: i tried its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute for the Class User in the Controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public class RegisterController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user,Model m) {         
    User user=new User();
    m.addAttribute(user);
    return "RegistrationSuccess";
}
```